# What should I do if I want to ask an almost duplicate question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, exact-duplicates

There already exists a question very like the one I want to ask, with a very partial answer by the OP. I want to ask the same question but restricted to a special case, for which I hope more can be said.

Should I post a new question? Edit the existing one to add that I'm interested in the special case? Something else?

Comment: If you do, you should link to the older question and answers, indicate how your question is different and deserves a separate answer, and why the answers to the old question do not satisfy the new question.  Gerhard "There Should Be A Reason" Paseman, 2018.03.12.

Comment: Even though this forum is a community effort, I advise against editing the question to add your special case.  Asking here is good, and getting explicit approval (in the form of comments or meta postings) from the original poster, or the moderators, or the community is better.  Gerhard "There Should Be Some Agreement" Paseman, 2018.03.12.

Comment: This is the question I want to re-ask: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/250809/when-does-a-characteristic-subgroup-remain-characteristic-in-the-profinite-compl  The special case I'm interested in is when F is a free group of finite rank, and K is a finite index subgroup. I'm also more interested in necessary conditions rather than sufficient.Do you think this justifies opening a new question?

Comment: It can, if you frame the question right.  Not only do you need to mention the specifics of your special case, link to the original question, and mention what else is wanted, but you should motivate why looking at the specialization is warranted.  Even if it does get considered as a duplicate, you can use the comment section to get more feedback, and hopefully something that helps.  Gerhard "So Give It A Try" Paseman, 2018.03.14.